# How can I save a figure in tiff with 600 dpi with compression using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently, I decided to port to Matplotlib from MATLAB for plotting my graphs. In MATLAB, what I would do is just go to files>export>render and then choose 600 dpi and then select apply to figure and then export. In Matplotlib, I am using the command savefig from the matplotlib library as

```
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
    orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
    transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
    frameon=None).
```

Then I set dpi to 600 and .tiff as the output format. This works fine except that the file is very large ~32 mb. Well obviously, I can't use this much big of a file in a journal manuscript. I would like to know if there is a way to incorporate a compression to the file so that the image file can be obtained with a smaller size with no loss in the resolution.

Comment: Is `*.tiff`required by the journal? Maybe you could save as a vector graphic instead. Depending on your plot the file-size might drastically decrease.

Comment: Why are you calling `savefig` with the same arguments as the defaults? I can see that you just copied the docstring, just it makes no sense.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Like I said, I am just getting started on Matplotlib. I changed, format to 'tiff' and dpi to 600.

Comment: @Nohs Journals publised by the American Society of Mechanical Engineers (ASME) asks for .tiff. Well then I will just use eps format and import it to tiff from Scribus or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Since `matplotlib` version 3.1.0 it is now possible to [directly pass parameters to PIL when saving a figure via the kwarg `pil_kwarg`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=pil_kwargs):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.savefig('/tmp/foo.tiff', dpi=600, format="tiff", pil_kwargs={"compression": "tiff_lzw"})
```

But beware of typos, since `savefig` seem to silently swallow unsupported kwargs, e.g. `pil_kwargssss`...

The feature was introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13094) which superseded the [PR linked by Ignacio Vergara Kausel in his response](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8530).

Answer (score 1):

As of date it's not possible to add compression for `tiff` format. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8530) and a worked [solution](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/8531) but has not seen progress since May last year or so.

In the worked solution there is a proposed workflow and quoting

> ... generate huge TIFF image files with MPL, then import them in PIL, save
>   them in PIL using compression of the TIFF and then discarding the
>   uncompressed TIFF files.

The [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) project has some `tiff` image saving [functionality](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.external.tifffile.html) with compression, it might help you depending on your use case.

Most likely the journal accepts other formats besides `tiff`. Then you can go for `png` or `jpeg` which with a DPI of 600 would work fine for basically all purposes of a journal.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work. I will stick with vector graphics for the time being. Hopefully, this issue is addressed in the near future. Thank you.

Comment: It's not that much work, just somewhat annoying. It can be part of your whole figure processing sequence.